# Tangent Vector of Circle

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to solve the following problem. I am stuck while I was thinking of the tangent vectors.

How do I construct an explicit diffeomorphism between $TS^1$ and $S^1\times\Bbb{R}$?

So my question is how does $TS^1$ look like?
I know it is disjoint union of Tangent Spaces at every point $z \in S^1$. But can anyone explain how does it look like in $R^2$?

I think it is the tangent at the point $z\in S_1$. I cannot see how that is a vector space. I read that the tangent space is a vector space too. Can anyone explain me with a diagram. It would help a lot.

Edit 1:
Wikipedia shows the red coloured lines as tangent space of a point. But isn't it supposed to be a vector space?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle#cite_note-disjoint-1

Comment: One explicit construction is : $T\mathbb S^1= \{x,\xi \in (\mathbb R^2)^2 | \quad \| x\| =1 \text{ et } \langle x,\xi \rangle = 0 \}$.

Comment: Then, at a point $x \in \mathbb S^1$, $T_x \mathbb S^1 = \{\xi \in\mathbb R^2 |  \langle x,\xi \rangle = 0 \}$ is indeed a vector space.

Comment: @SolubleFish . Agreed. But when I recall that a tangent to a curve is a straight line which touches the curve only at one point. This line may not pass through the origin. (0,0). That's why I am confused how it is a vector space.

Comment: The tangent vector is the direction of the line. The line itself is an affine space (when you embed your manifold in $\mathbb R^n$).

Comment: @SolubleFish, I couldn't get your last point. Can you please explain in more details?

Comment: The tangent space to $\mathbb S^1$ at $x$ is *not* the line in $\mathbb R$a which is tangent to the circle at $x$. To have a vector space you need to translate it by $-x$.

Comment: Got your point. One more question. Alternative definitions of Tangent Space is it is a collection of derivatives satisfying leibniz rule (linear map from $ C^{\infty}(M) \to \mathbb{R}$.) How does every element of tangent space(tangent vector at $(1,0)$ translated by $(1,0)$ define a linear map from  $ C^{\infty}(M)\to \mathbb{R}$?